# If the defendant declines the plaintiff's counsel's request to give evidence, then how did the latter err?

Tags: england-and-wales, advocacy

<sub>Source: pp 182-183, *The Art of the Advocate* (1993) by Richard Du Cann QC.</sub>

> Less fortunate was a Mr Barker in 1896, who suddenly found 
>   that all his furniture had been sold by a man named Shalless 
>   through a firm of auctioneers. Counsel for Mr Barker was con- 
>   fident he could prove his case against both Shalless and the 
>   auctioneers for 'converting' the furniture (selling it against his 
>   will and keeping the proceeds) by cross-examining Shalless. Mr 
>   Shalless was of the same opinion, and although present in court 
>   during the hearing, he declined to give evidence on his own behalf. Determined not to be foiled by  this  ruse[,] counsel then 
>   applied to the Judge for leave to call Shalless himself. **[1.]** The Judge 
>   pointed out that if he had wanted to call Shalless he should have 
>   done so as part of his own case. He went on:
>
> > ... in granting the Plaintiff's application ... I should be making a 
> >     precedent which would, if established, lead to an improper amount of 
> >     laxity in the conduct of the plaintiff's case. **[End of 1.]**
>
> This is a convoluted way of saying that the advocate must 
>   make up his mind before the case begins how he is going to 
>   conduct it: that he cannot wait until he sees which way the wind 
>   is blowing and then call extra evidence. The basis of the rule is 
>   more fundamental. A defendant, whether in criminal or civil 
>   courts, is entitled to know the whole of the evidence proving the 
>   case against him before he is obliged to answer it. That is the 
>   principle. Practice demands its enforcement if only because trials 
>   last quite long enough already. If purely confirmatory evidence 
>   in rebuttal were allowed, it would be difficult to prevent evidence 
>   in surrebuttal (evidence called by a defendant in rebuttal of 
>   rebuttal evidence) being called with equal frequency, and it 
>   would be difficult to see the end of any trial.

2. I do not understand 1. Mr Barker's counsel had already asked Shalless to give evidence, but Shalless declined. So why did the Judge still blame  Mr Barker's counsel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He should have summonsed him to appear as a witness for the plaintiff.

Comment: +1 This is what I got from it as well. The plaintiff's counsel bet on the defendant testifying in his defense, and he lost the bet. The judge's opinion is basically "no takesies backsies."

Comment: @Patrick87: I would love for that to become an official legal phrase, in the vein of the Latin phrases that are currently used.